# Order array multi-dimensional

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that looks like this:

```
$cars = array (
  array(
    'a' => 'audi',
    'b' => 'a4'),
  array(
    'a' => 'peugeot',
    'b' => '306'),
  array(
    'a' => 'audi',
    'b' => 'a4'),
  array(
    'a' => 'audi',
    'b' => 'a5'),
  array(
    'a' => 'peugeot',
    'b' => '106'),
  array(
    'a' => 'peugeot',
    'b' => '106'),
);
```

I need to order arrays like this to (id is the same as name):

```
name => audi
id=> audi
data => a4 => 2
        a5 => 1
name => peugeot
id=> peugeot
data => 306 => 1
        106 => 2
```

So the car brands need to be grouped an the car types counted.

I already have this code; but that is only for the group part and the count part is missing.

```
function mergeAndOrder($data){

    // set group arrays
    $i = 0; $group1 = array();

    // loop trough array
    $array = array(); $array2 = array();        
    if($data != null){
        foreach($data AS $row){

            // search and order level1
            $search = array_search($row->a,$group1);

            // this object is not found
            if(is_int($search) == false){

                $group1[$i] = $row->a;
                $array[$i]['id'] = $row->a;
                $array[$i]['name'] = $row->a;
                $array[$i]['data'] = array();

                $i++;   

            }               

        }                               
    }

    return $array;
}
```

Does somebody know an solution for this case? Thanks!

--- INPUT (part of) ---
a = lease company in this case

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [b] => AUDI
            [a] => LPN
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [b] => AUDI
            [a] => LPN
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [b] => AUDI
            [a] => LPN
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [b] => AUDI
            [a] => LPN
        )
```

--- OUTPUT (part of) ---

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => LPN
            [name] => LPN
            [data] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => ARV
            [name] => ARV
            [data] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => ARVB
            [name] => ARVB
            [data] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => LPD
            [name] => LPD
            [data] => Array
                (
                )

        )

)

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => LPN
            [name] => LPN
            [data] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => ARV
            [name] => ARV
            [data] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => ARVB
            [name] => ARVB
            [data] => Array
                (
                )

        )
```

Comment: What does `echo '<pre>'.print_r($data,1).'</pre>';` output?

Comment: Post the input and output array with php code plz.

Comment: @JelleP That looks completely different. Now your input is a class and it has different attributes, basically just 4 identical objects.

Comment: @AndreschSerj you're right about that input array. It is an object indeed but the case stays the same. Is my question clear or is there something not explained yet?

Comment: Well, your input changed. That's weird. Anywho: You do an array_search to find pre-existing entries already. You just need to use the result to alter the state.
Consider reading the array_search documentation http://de1.php.net/array_search

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The function i made works well but does not count b in the data field. I don't know how to do that. The array could be anything. a is leading and b need to be counted..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, this should do what you want.

```
function mergeAndOrder ($data) {

    $output = array();
    foreach ($data as $item) {

        $id    = $item->a;
        $value = $item->b;

        if (!array_key_exists($id, $output)) {
            $output[$id] = array('id' => $id, 'name' => $id, 'data' => array());
        }

        if (!array_key_exists($value, $output[$id]['data'])) {
            $output[$id]['data'][$value] = 0;
        }

        $output[$id]['data'][$value]++;
    }

    // Order by name element
    uasort($output, function ($a, $b) {
        return strcasecmp($a['name'], $b['name']);
    });

    return $output;
}
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [audi] => Array
        (
            [id] => audi
            [name] => audi
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [a4] => 2
                    [a5] => 1
                )

        )

    [peugeot] => Array
        (
            [id] => peugeot
            [name] => peugeot
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [306] => 1
                    [106] => 2
                )

        )
)
```